# sql select statement exclude rows of same with different values

Tags: sql

I'm using Sql Server 2008 and trying to achieve as below:

Existing Table:

```
+--------+-------------+--------+
| ID     | COUNTRY     | STATUS |
+--------+-------------+--------+
| 1      | UK          |   0    |
| 2      | UK          |   1    |
| 3      | USA         |   0    |
| 4      | Greece      |   0    |
| 5      | Italy       |   1    |
+-------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to query Where STATUS =0 and at the same time exclude all those rows if same Country has two different STATUS (Exclude UK in above table in my case)

Expected Result:

```
+--------+-------------+--------+
| ID     | COUNTRY     | STATUS |
+--------+-------------+--------+
| 3      | USA         |   0    |
| 4      | Greece      |   0    |
+-------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried anything? This isn't a "do my work for me" thing you know.

Comment: Sorry for that, very beginner in SQL and tried  a lot to achieve on my own but no luck, that's the reason i'm here..

Comment: If you need to do a query like this, you have very likely serious problems in your database design. You should have it reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM  Table1
WHERE STATUS = 0 AND
Country NOT IN (SELECT Country FROM Table1 WHERE Status = 1)
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f0b4/1)**

**Outpit:**

```
+--------+-------------+--------+
| ID     | COUNTRY     | STATUS |
+--------+-------------+--------+
| 3      | USA         |   0    |
| 4      | Greece      |   0    |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select * From tbl x 
where STATUS=0 and
    (select COUNT(*) from tbl y 
    where y.COUNTRY=x.COUNTRY and y.STATUS=1)=0
```